# count records in two different access file using query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have two ms access 2003(.mdb) file one is student record the other is the test scores.

```
student record.mdb contents
tables:
basicinfo
schoolsattended
familyinfo

test scores.mdb contents
tables:
verbal
written
```

as you can see my student record.mdb has 3 table and the test score.mdb has 2, the important tables are only basicinfo, verbal and written dont mind the rest. what i want to do is count how many students got the specific scaled score using query for verbal and written as shown below.

```
[basicinfo](table1-student record.mdb)
[Name     age     rawscoreverbal    rawscorewritten](fields)
mark      16      6                 6
paul      17      5                 5
bryan     16      8                 8
jenny     16      7                 7

verbal(table1-test scores.mdb)
[rawscore     scaledscore](fields)
1                1
2                1
3                2
4                2
5                3
6                3
7                4
8                4
9                5
10               5

writen(table2-test scores.mdb)
[rawscore     scaledscore]fields
1                1
2                1
3                2
4                2
5                3
6                3
7                4
8                4
9                5
10               5

expected output

Verbal:
Scaled Score      Count
1                 0
2                 0
3                 2
4                 2
5                 0

written:
Scaled Score      Count
1                 0
2                 0
3                 2
4                 2
5                 0
```

I've tried using this code

```
SELECT v.scaledscore as [Scaled Score], count(i.rawscore) as [Count]
FROM verbal v LEFT JOIN basicinfo i ON v.rawscore = i.rawscore
GROUP BY v.scaledscore
```

it works but only if all tables are together in one .mdb file. But i need two separate .mdb files since i have something else to do with it. I dont wanna explain it since its a very long story. Is it possible? if it is, can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the MDB where you want to run the query, link to a table in the other MDB.  If you make the link name the same as the table name, the query will find what it needs.

To link to an external table in Access 2003, from the main menu choose File->Get External Data->Link Tables.  From there, the dialogs will guide you through selecting the database and then the table.

If Access 2007, find the Access icon above Import on the External Data section of the ribbon.

Comment: do i need the other mdb file to be present in the same directory with the other mdb? because ill be updating it regularly.

Comment: The 2 mdb files do not have to be in the same directory.

Comment: ow wow its finally linked! hurrah! well about the code do i need to chance any of the previous code i did? and if i move the files from different location will it still link?

Comment: The properties for the link include the location of the db which holds the linked table.  So if you move the db, you will need to update the link properties.  With Access 2003, Tools->Database Utilities->Linked Table Manager.  I have no idea how linked tables will require changes to your existing code; depends on the code, I suppose.